# Remove shutdown-restart-logout-suspend prompt in greeter login screen Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, shutdown, lightdm, unity-greeter

[image]

The problem is when i use this Virtualbox command from host Ubuntu 16.04 to VM Ubuntu 14.04:

```
vboxmanage controlvm "Ubuntu Desktop 14.04" acpipowerbutton
```

it pops up with that shutdown prompt like in the attached picture.
If i have logged in already, it used to pop up until i went into dconf-editor
and changed this to true: apps - indicator-session - suppress shutdown, restart

Then it never prompted and fixed that issue, but in login screen before logging on (like in the attached picture), it still prompts me and i dont want it to! i just want to send shutdown graceful signal to the VM.

I tried this at the end of this article: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/07/remove-shutdown-log-out-dialog-box/
But it still pops up!

Please can someone help get rid of this and to be able to shutdown the VM gracefully without stupid prompts??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the solution to this, was to add

"/sbin/shutdown -h now"  at the very beginning of this script:
/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh

now no matter if the screen is locked or not yet logged in, as soon as an acpipowerbutton command is sent, or the power button of the pc is pressed, no confirmation dialogs anymore, just straight forward shutdown. finally!

References: [How to enable the pc power button at the lock screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531732/how-to-enable-the-pc-power-button-at-the-lock-screen)